# how to set listview in half screen on Map view in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:background="#00ad9a"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dip"
            android:src="@drawable/backbutton" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/centertext" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Llayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_linearHeader1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <com.lociiapp.MapWrapperLayout
                    android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lastSeenDatetextview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:text="Time"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="#07000000"
                         android:gravity="bottom">

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
                        </ListView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/typing"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.lociiapp.MapWrapperLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/recciverImage"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/imge" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rlayout"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.86"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroundline"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="Write Message"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ababab" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
                android:layout_width="79dp"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my XMl i am trying to display listview in half screen and then it should scroll its item basically i want to display only 3 item  .
currently my screen is looking like this [image]

while i have to display list-view only half screen please tell suggest me where am doing wrong i have to display listview half screen in which i want to display only 3 item ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="#07000000"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
                        </ListView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/typing"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                    </LinearLayout>
```

replace this  and set ur height of linear layout according to given screen and enjoy!!!